# How to sort a hashtable of class values by their property in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, hashtable

I have a Hashtable in C# like.

```
Hashtable people = new Hashtable();
people.Add(0, new Person("Jimmi", "Hendrix"));
people.Add(1, new Person("Bob", "Dylan"));
people.Add(2, new Person("Jim", "Morrison"));
```

How would I sort this hash by the people last name  with Linq?

```
class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName): this(firstName, lastName, DateTime.Now)
    {}

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = birthDate;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: All has-table based types (Dictionary, HashSet, Hashtable) don't have concept of ordereing. If you clarify what you actually want to achieve someone may suggest more appropriate type or approach to achieve that.

Comment: Note that for code running against supported .Net framework (and not 1.x) using `Dictionary<int, Person>` would be better choice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = people.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(kvp => ((Person)kvp.Value).LastName);
```

the result becomes `OrderedEnumerable` though, because putting back to `Hashtable` will forget the order.\

EDIT:
If you are looking for a way to enumerate the result and pull out the id's along with the `Person` information, this is how you do it:

```
// this is the original answer
var result = people.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(kvp => ((Person)kvp.Value).LastName);

// now convert it to an array
var listToIterate = result.ToArray();
foreach(var item in listToIterate)
{
    var id = item.Key;
    var person = (Person)item.Value;
}
```

Hope this helps...!

Comment: Sorry, never worked with OrderedEnumerables how would I iterate over this?

Comment: You can convert it to array with `ToArray()` or to list with `ToList()` at the end. To iterate.... `foreach(var item in result)`

Comment: @nebulus: simple - just invoke the `ToList()` method of the `IOrderedEnumerable` and assign the result to a variable. Then you can enumerate it as you would a regular list.

Comment: Argh. Let me edit @kurakura88's answer with the full solution that you are looking for.

Comment: Not bad! It works, last thing how would I sort it when the names have numbers, order should not be 1, 10, 2 but 1, 2... 10. Cheers!

Comment: LOL... ok, since you now understand how casting and linq ordering works, how about you think about how `Convert.ToInt32()` will fit into the grand scheme of things?

Comment: @code4life BTW, you don't really need to convert it to array to iterate though. I was mentioning the To Array in case if nebulus would like to store it into more known type.

Comment: Okay, Maestro. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kurakura88: however, you should convert it - in order to ensure that deferred linq execution does not occur and to ensure that the ordering that you "snapshotted" remains pristine. The `ToArray` (the `ToList` is ok too) is a good practice to follow if you care about preserving the order.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non generic (IMO legacy) data type. So you will need to poke it a bit to get what you want.

`people.Values.OfType<Person>().OrderBy(p => p.LastName);`

First you want to sort the values, but that isn't generic, so use `OfType`. Now you can play with the standard Linq operators like `OrderBy`

Comment: Okay, thanks... How do I iterate over that and still get the key pair?

Comment: As per Alexei's suggestion, dont use hashtable. It is an out dated type. Use Dictionary<TKey, TValue>

Comment: Okay, I still don't get how to use this. I need to output this as and array and see the ids.

Comment: @LeeCampbell: I wouldn't say "don't use HashTable because it's an outdated type". That's basically making a huge assumption that the problem domain that you are assuming is orthogonal to all problem domains in a global manner. The OP might be under specific constraints and TBH, it *is* an interesting problem, to extract a sorted list from a HashTable. It's exactly the sort of problem we may face when maintaining legacy code.